# OS-ticket configuring POP says IMAP not available

Tags: php, installation, osticket

I'm trying to configure the email-settings of osticket.

I choose POP and enter the credentials, but when I hit save, I get the message that IMAP is not available and I'd have to compile PHP with activated IMAP.

I don't want to use IMAP and I cannot compile PHP on the server I'm using...

Any ideas what I could do about this?

On a sidenote: I signed up at the osticket forums, but I can't find a link to open a new thread? I'm feeling kinda stupid... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may have used the server and port that is used only for IMAP by your email hosting provider.

You will need to enter the server and port that is used for POP3, so please double-check the email server info you entered and let me know.